# HTTP error 404 when publishing nServiceBus message in WebApi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-404, ravendb, nservicebus

I created a WebApi project that publishes a message that should be handled through nServiceBus.
It works in IIS Express (from VS.NET) but not in IIS 8.5 (in the same machine).

The error is a 404 thrown from RavenDB on publishing the message, but I can't get details on the error.

I tried publishing messages from an nServiceBus host, works fine. From an ASP.NET MVC web site hosted in IIS, also works. It only fails when it's published from a WebApi project hosted in IIS.

The error is then an HTTP 404 and the message doesn't get into the message queue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this how your service will be deployed? RavenDB running on the same box as the IIS? Are you testing a scenario that will not exist in your production environment?

Comment: Hi Chris. This is my development environment, I'm not thinking how this will be deployed to Test/Acc/Prod yet. Would having Raven and IIS in the same box be a problem?

Comment: since this is more a trouble-shooting/debugging question it would be better suited to being on the forum https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/particularsoftware